# PostGIS ST_Intersection of polygons can return lines

Tags: postgis

When clipping the polygons of one table with polygons in another, ST_Intersection can return a set of results that can be handled with ST_Dump. The returned multiple geometries are not necessarily ST_Polygon but also ST_LineString (probably also a point). So when running a query

```
INSERT INTO c (geom)
  (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom))).geom
  FROM a INNER JOIN b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom));
```

when trying to populate the table "c" with clipped polygons, it fails with
ERROR:  Geometry type (LineString) does not match column type (Polygon)

I did another nested SELECT statement so only the polygon geometries came through, like:

```
INSERT INTO c (geom)
  (SELECT geom FROM
    (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom))).geom
    FROM a INNER JOIN b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom))) AS cl
    WHERE ST_GeometryType(cl.geom)='ST_Polygon');
```

As this is a bit cumbersome I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution for dropping invalid geometries?

Comment: BTW, I put <!-- language: lang-sql --> before the code blocks but there is still no highligting. Any hints for a noob?

Comment: To format code simply paste it in, select it and use the Code Sample button **`{}`** above the Question editing window.

Comment: Hm, I did that, the code is marked as "code", but the keywords are still not colored.

Comment: I don't normally try to prettify SQL code here but I just found a Meta posting that looks useful at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90521/prettify-hates-sql-or-how-do-i-get-prettify-to-properly-handle-sql - have you left a "blank line between the comment and the code"?

Comment: An intersection of two geometries may yield *any* type of geometry, so I think your current solution is the most direct.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I did leave a blank line between the comment and code but no still no highlighting. I'll deal with that when I receive enlightenment :-)

Comment: No problem - Meta SO (or the coming [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)) will be the place to try and sort out prettifying SQL code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be a good spot to use an SQL-language function.  Here's a quick one that should work for this situation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PolygonalIntersection(a geometry, b geometry)
RETURNS geometry AS $$
SELECT ST_Collect(geom)
FROM 
(SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a, b))).geom 
UNION ALL
-- union in an empty polygon so we get an 
-- empty geometry instead of NULL if there
-- is are no polygons in the intersection
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON EMPTY')) SQ
WHERE ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_Polygon';
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This will retain the polygonal components of an intersection, but throw away everything else.  It always returns a MultiPolygon, even if you have one or no components.

```
WITH 
      square   as (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 0  1,  1  1,  1  0, 0 0))') AS geom),
biggersquare   as (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10  0, 0 0))') AS geom),
adjacentsquare as (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 1  0,  1 -1, -1 -1, 0 0))') AS geom)   

SELECT ST_AsText(PolygonalIntersection(square.geom, biggersquare.geom))
  FROM square, biggersquare;
--"MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0)))"

SELECT ST_AsText(PolygonalIntersection(square.geom, adjacentsquare.geom))
  FROM square, adjacentsquare;
--"MULTIPOLYGON(EMPTY)"
```

Answer (score 5):

Very good answer from @dbaston. 
However, returning an empty geometry instead of null might cause issues because returned empty geometry has no srid.
St_Intersection might return MultiPolygon as well. 
This updated function was really useful for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PolygonalIntersection(a geometry, b geometry)
RETURNS geometry AS $$
SELECT ST_Collect(geom)
FROM 
(SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a, b))).geom 
) SQ
WHERE ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_Polygon' OR ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_MultiPolygon';
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```