# ST_intersection returns erroneous polygons

Tags: qgis, postgis, clip, intersection

I am trying to perform a clip by attribute in PostGIS between two shapefile containing 3000 polygons. 
Both shapefiles are free of errors (checked with topology checker), both shapefile are using EPSG:3857.

The following query works well for 99.9% of polygons, but for some it creates incomplete polygons or misses some when loaded in QGIS. The polygons with errors do have the same name used as a clipping attribute. I really don't understand why some polygons fail to be generated compared to others.

```
create table poly_20m_checked (gid serial PRIMARY KEY, polyID text, geometry geometry);
    insert into poly_20m_checked(polyID, geometry)
    select
    a.name as polyID,
    ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom) as geometry
    FROM donut20m a, symm20m b
    WHERE a.name=b.name
    Group by polyID, geometry
```

donut20m:
[image: donut]
symm20m:
[image: symm]
result (one polygon is missing):
[image: result]

Sample files that contains 4 polygons, among which one that returns an error (moved to make location anonymous):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7mqg7Gq1NGVVVVsbTZqMlVhZnc

The reason I am doing it in PostGIS is that I don't think there's a way to clip polygons in 2 shapefiles by using attribute in QGIS. What could be causing errors?
I am very open to suggestion to get around the problem. I thought about spliting polygons by ID and then clip each pair of shapefiles but haven't really managed to code it.

EDIT: download for sample polygons. 
EDIT2: Tried to simplify geometries by 1m, which makes thing a bit better, but still bugy

Comment: I think it will be hard to debug this without your sharing the actual geometries donut20m and symm20m.

Comment: Good idea, here is a sample that contains 4 polygons, among which one that returns an error: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7mqg7Gq1NGVVVVsbTZqMlVhZnc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ST_Intersection functions occasionally gives a GeometryCollection where you wouldn't expect it. This is the case with your data. When you inspect the output with ST_AsText you will see that the second donut from the top outputs both a polygon and a linestring. This linestring is bogus, since it has only 2 identical coordinates, but due to some rounding process, postgis (or likely GEOS) sees this as a seperate entity. This especially happens with polygons that are supposed to be precisely overlapping.

The solution is simple, always use a ST_Dump on the output of ST_Intersection. Example:

```
select
    a.name as polyID,
    (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom))).geom as geometry
    FROM tmp.sampledonut20m   a, tmp.samplesymm20m b
    WHERE a.name=b.name
    Group by polyID, geometry
```

Use a filter later on if you want to get rid of the linestrings. There is a nice example with a function from Dan Baston over here: [PostGIS ST_Intersection of polygons can return lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89231/postgis-st-intersection-of-polygons-can-return-lines)

Comment: you can also use the st_collectionextract

Comment: and isnt group by a geometry not the right way to go?

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your answer. it's working perfectly now on the larger dataset. It does make some polygon as multipolygon but a little dissolve by attribute in QGIS resolves that nicely. Is there a way to do that in PostGIS to save an import/export step?

Comment: I guess multipolygon is correct in some  cases, since your donut is being cut into more than 1 piece. Or do you mean 'more than 1 polygon' instead of 'multipolygon' ?

Comment: Yes sorry, I do mean more than one polygon

Comment: In that case, you can do a ST_Collect around the output of ST_Dump. http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html  I think ziggy's comments also make sense, you should definitely look into using ST_CollectionExtract and that group by wouldn't make sense there.